# ApplicationShortcuts, is there any way to not open the app and only execute some actions such as Play/Pause?

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplicationshortcutitem

I have an audio app and I want to control play/pause with `ApplicationShortcutItem` directly, but I don't want to open the app.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is **not possible** to leave an app in the background when choosing a Home screen quick action.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationshortcutitem) of `UIApplicationShortcutItem`:

> When a user chooses one of your Home screen quick actions, **the system launches or resumes your app** and `UIKit` calls the `application(_:performActionFor:completionHandler:)` method in your app delegate.

Comment: Actually I can control play/pause with shortcutItem, so open the UI of App is not necessary for me.